# iOS - Validation for consumable products

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am wondering where I should store the receipt data when the validation for a consumable item failed.

To validate the receipt, we have to send a receipt data which is gained from below code to our server, but for some reasons it might be failed.

```
// Load the receipt from the app bundle.
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
if (!receipt) { /* No local receipt -- handle the error. */ }
/* ... Send the receipt data to your server ... */
```

In case for that, we have to store the receipt data in the app to send the receipt data again.

I tried using NSUserDefaults but I found that the data will disappear when the user delete the app itself.

How do you deal with the case?

Comment: Why do you need to store it in the app? Just load it again from the file system, which is where it is stored for you.

Comment: Yea, but it will be deleted after uninstalling the app, right?

Comment: Yes it will, but it will be put back again when the app is re-installed.